# How can I prevent an application from showing on the Dock?

Tags: macos, dock

Working with Mac OS X 10.9.5 (Mavericks).

I have an application that is launched with my session and displays its menu from the status bar.

Also, I would like to know if there is a way to prevent this application from also showing on the Dock since I have the possibility to access its menu from the status bar.

If I remove the icon from the Dock, then the application quits.

I've been searching on the web for a solution, I found that modifying the ***info.plist*** of the *content* of the app adding :

```
<true/>
<key>LSUIElement</key>
<true/>
```

could solve the issue, but in vain, after that modification, the app keeps "jumping" but doesn't launch. So I recover the code as it was before.

Comment: According to Apple doc: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-108256 this should be a "string" not "boolean". So instead of `<true/>` try `<string>1</string>`.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the `Info.plist` has made sandboxed applications crash on launch since 10.8.

You can for example run

```
lsappinfo setinfo -app TextEdit ApplicationType=UIElement
```

after opening TextEdit to hide TextEdit from the Dock temporarily, but I don't know how to make the change permanent.

Comment: It doesn't work in macOS mojave (10.14.4), someone could confirm this?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a long shot ...

Is that app one that is shown in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items

If you check the box there to hide the app, does it still show in the Dock?

Comment: sorry for long response delay. Unfortunately yes it still shows in the Dock even if it's hidden in System Preferences > Users & Groups > Login Items.

Comment: If you check the `hide` box for an application in system preferences, it will launch without any windows appearing, but will still show up in the dock.